# About Custom Payment Method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I Have Created a custom payment method which enabled in admin and showing in

one-step checkout page, But on clicking the proceed order the order payment

is not redirecting to a success page, Can anyone help me in these

Thanks In advance

Comment: Please, add code of the method to your question

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller:

`$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));`

**EDIT:**

Why do you need to **redirect** from a **model** ? generally the **redirects** should happen in **controllers**. However if you have some exception in your case and you should to redirect from a model, try this code below:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();       
return;
```

Comment: Can I call these in model also @prince

Comment: Look my update please.